# Multi-core OpenCV denoising

Tags: python, image, opencv, multiprocessing

I have ~40,000 JPEG images from the [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/siim-isic-melanoma-classification) melanoma classification competition. I created the following functions to denoise the images:

```
# Denoising functions
def denoise_single_image(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(f'../data/jpeg/{img_path}')
    dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img, 10,10,7,21)
    cv2.imwrite(f'../processed_data/jpeg/{img_path}', dst)
    print(f'{img_path} denoised.')

def denoise(data):
    img_list = os.listdir(f'../data/jpeg/{data}')
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        tqdm.tqdm(executor.map(denoise_single_image, (f'{data}/{img_path}' for img_path in img_list)))
```

The `denoise` function uses `concurrent.futures` to map the `denoise_single_image()` function over the full list of images.

`ProcessPoolExecutor()` was used based on the assumption of denoising as a CPU-heavy task, rather than an I/O-intensitve task.

As it stands now, this function takes hours to run. With a CUDA-configured Nvidia GPU and 6 GB VRAM, I'd like to optimize this further.

Is there any way to improve the speed of this function?

[Multi-core processing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)
[OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. What Python version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You may look at opencv [Transparent API](https://learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/)

```
#
imgUMat = cv2.UMat(img)
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(imgUMat, 10,10,7,21)
#
```